# java ftp delete all files without deleting folders

Tags: java, file, ftp

How to remove all files on ftp the server without deleting folders using Java.

For example, i have files that in the folders like:

/TEST/DOCUMENT/1/111.txt

/TEST/DOCUMENT/1/222.txt

/TEST/DOCUMENT/2/333.txt

/TEST/DOCUMENT/2/444.txt

/TEST/PDF/1/111.pdf

/TEST/PDF/1/222.pdf

/TEST/PDF/2/333.pdf

I need to delete only files not folders

Comment: Use `FTPClient` iterate over the files in any directory using `listFiles(String pathname)` method and delete each file. Read More about FTPClient methods @ http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Comment: @Amogh Yeah, i know about FTPClient, a thought java have some library that can delete all files from root folder including subfolders. Ok, if it isnt possible i will use FTPClient as earlier,  but its so hard to delete each file over 250 folders

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the system, or do you want to do it "over" ftp?
if you have access, this software an option "delete only files" so if you delete a folder, it will delete all files under it and leave the folders empty.
http://www.softpedia.com/get/File-managers/JFileProcessor.shtml https://github.com/stant/jfileprocessor

Will also let you search for files with glob or regex, in subfolders to X or all depth, by name, size, date. You can save to a List window or file. Then you can run a groovy (think java) script to do whatever you want to the list of files; zip or tar them, modify the list strings like sed, delete, move, copy files, grep or ls -l them, whatever. It will also let you massage your list like add to, delete from, subtract one list from another.